# Matlab: generate two random numbers which are always different

Tags: matlab, random, colors

I want to plot two grey squares, one of which is always darker than the other (for a test participant to decide in each trial which is darker).

I've set up the trials using

```
for N=1:20
    w=rand(1)
    z=rand(1)
    % ...
end
```

And when I plot my squares I've set the color of one square using

```
'markerfacecolor', [w w w]
```

and set the second square similarly, using `z`.

**The problem is**: The two random numbers shouldn't be the same, because when this is the case the participant can't really decide which square is darker.

Can anyone help me to figure out how I can prevent the two random numbers being the same as each other within each loop?

Answer (score 2):

"Shouldn't be the same" seems like a loose tolerance definition in this context, for instance would you allow `w = 0.5`, `z = 0.50001`? They would be pretty similar greys!

Let's define a tolerance, and find a random `w` and `z`

```
tol = 0.01; % forced difference between w and z
w = rand;   % rand returns one value by default, don't have to use rand(1)
z = rand;
```

Now loop until `z` is either less than `w-tol` or greater than `w+tol`,

```
while abs(w-z) > tol
    z = rand;
end
```

---

**Note**: You may want to add an iteration counter, so the while loop is ended after, say, 1000 attempts! Be aware that setting `tol` too large could cause this to take a lot longer.

---

**Full example** in the form of your example:

```
tol = 0.1; % larger tolerance
for N = 1:20
    w = rand; z = rand;
    while abs(w-z) > tol; z = rand; end;

    % >> w = 0.8045
    % >> z = 0.8169
    %    z = 0.7322
    %    z = 0.1895 % tolerance satisfied, stop while loop and continue

    % Do your trial here...
end
```

---

**Repeatability**

If you wanted to do the exact same trials on multiple subjects, you would want the greys to be the same! Either run the randomising function once and store the output values for re-use, or reset the seed of the random number generator using [`rng`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since by definition the variable is "random", then you should not be naturally able to do that.

Given a large enough space from which you are picking the random value uniformly, it is pretty cheap computationally to simple add a while loop inside after obtaining w. Keep looping and choosing a new z until z is not equal to w. For you application the consequences are extremely negligible.